# Simplifying a formula with summation

Tags: summation

I have seen on a data-mining tutorial this sort of formula simplification:

[image]

to

[image]

(consider $\bar x$ to be the sum of all $x_i$ dividied by n)

So I was wondering if I can apply the same simplification for this formula?

[image]

and if yes, what are the strategies for doing so?

Comment: I got a feeling that this uses some unwritten stochastic assumption like $x_i, y_i$ being samples from independent random variables to get rid of cross terms. If so, you cannot obtain the second formula from just rearranging the first one. I am really not sure though.

Comment: @graphtheory92: I don't think the same simplification works, because in the third formula the "average" terms $\overline R_u$ is dependent on the index of summation, which is not the case in the first formula. Also, what is the average with respect to?

Comment: Ok, that is what I was thinking. The average consider it to be a constant, since once I calculate $R_u$ is always calculated. So What I am actually thinking is to subtract $R_u$ to everything in advance